# Reinstall OS android on chinese phone Gusun JY809?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, custom-roms

I bought a Chinese phone, the Gusun JY809. I am satisfied with the phone itself but it still logs into chinese web apps and stores. Unfortunately, I am in the Czech Republic. I have tried to install CyanogenMod but I could not find the right one.

Are there any custom ROM options for this phone?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We're excited to have you here. Unfortunately, this phone is rather obscure and I'm not able to find any information about ROMs (or rooting, or the bootloader, or really anything) for it. I fear that you may not be able to change the software.

Comment: Not really news that sweet to my ears or stomage :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same phone and having the same difficulty on finding any info, so far I have been able to:

- **connect** to PC using [PDAnet auto drivers](http://www.gizbeat.com/1273/pdanet-adb-auto-driver-for-windows/)
- **root** using [Graphical Easy Root Tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2315346)
- install **ClockworkMod Recovery** [rua1 autoCWM v5.5.0.4](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=44660171&postcount=417)

Hope this helps.